# Encontrar o problema da minha lista de objetos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom estou fazendo está pergunta, pois ja tentei várias maneiras, porém não encontro o erro na lógica ou a utilização errada de alguma sintaxe no python.

Seria o seguinte, possuo esta classe:

```
class PalavraIndices(object):

 def __init__(self,palavra):
    self.palavra = palavra
    self.items_in_Indices = {}

def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.palavra)

def add_item(self, arquivo_indice, qtd_repeticao):
    if bool(self.items_in_Indices) == False: # dicionario estiver vazio
        self.items_in_Indices[arquivo_indice] = qtd_repeticao
    else:            
        if not arquivo_indice in self.items_in_Indices: #nome do arquivo base não existir
            self.items_in_Indices[arquivo_indice] = qtd_repeticao
        else:
            self.items_in_Indices[arquivo_indice] += qtd_repeticao

def imprime_indices(self):
    conteudo = self.palavra + ":"
    arquivos = list( self.items_in_Indices.keys() )
    arquivos.sort()
    for arq in arquivos:

        conteudo = conteudo + " %s,%s" %(arq, self.items_in_Indices[arq])

    print(conteudo)
```

Estou adicionando palavras como objetos a uma lista de objetos para marcar a quantidade e em qual arquivo a palavra aparece, tendo algo assim no final:

**Carro: (arq1,2),(arq2,1),(arq3,4)**

Guardo neste formato na classe, quando instancio um objeto(palavra), dentro deste objeto utilizo um dicionário.

possuo estás três listas:

```
ListaA = ['modo', 'consulta', 'diversos', 'militantes', 'acarreta', 
'processo', 'reformulacao', 'modernizacao', 'fluxo', 'informacoes', 
'diversos', 'poderes', 'mundo']

ListaB = ['evidentemente', 'determinacao', 'clara', 'objetivos', 'promove', 
'alavancagem', 'niveis', 'motivacao', 'departamental']

ListaC = ['gostaria', 'enfatizar', 'percepcao', 'dificuldades', 'cumpre', 
'papel', 'essencial', 'formulacao', 'diretrizes', 'desenvolvimento', 
'futuro', 'papel', 'arvore']
```

Esta função verifica se o objeto ja existe na lista de objeto

```
   def busca_index(lista_objetos,palavra):
     contador = 0
     aux = 0
     for objeto in lista_objetos:
      if(objeto.palavra == palavra):
          return contador
        contador += 1
     return -1
```

Função em que crio a lista de objetos:

```
def guarda_word(lista_palavras,lista_objeto,indice):
  existe = -1
  for palavra in lista_palavras:
     objetoPalavra = PalavraIndices(palavra)
     if bool(lista_objeto) == False: # a list de objeto esta vazia
         objetoPalavra.add_item(indice,1)
         lista_objeto.append(objetoPalavra)
     else:
         existe = busca_index(lista_objeto,palavra)
         if(existe != -1):
             lista_objeto[existe].add_item(indice,1)
             existe = -1
         else:
            objetoPalavra.add_item(indice,1)
            lista_objeto.append(objetoPalavra)
```

e por fim as chamadas:

```
lista_objeto = []

guarda_word(ListaA,lista_objeto,'arquivoA')
guarda_word(ListaB,lista_objeto,'arquivoB')
guarda_word(ListaC,lista_objeto,'arquivoC')

print("lista de objeto")
print(lista_objeto)

for objeto in lista_objeto:
   objeto.imprime_indices()
```

A Saída gerada é:

```
consulta
{'arquivoA': 13, 'arquivoB': 9, 'arquivoC': 13}
```

porém não esta contabilizando corretamente... Enfim.. não sei se deu pra compreender, e desculpa se ficou gigante esta pergunta... Mas caso alguém  se interessa em tentar encontra o porque cada palavra objeto não esta computando corretamente as quantidades de vezes que ela se repete.

Comment: Acho que você tá dificultando demais um problema simples, você necessariamente quer fazer por POO ou pode ser de outra maneira?

Comment: entao @RuyNeto é porque utilizando este objeto, das formas que eu pensei, seria a forma mais facil de se gravar  as informações de cada palavra naquele formato de saída. e neste caso não vejo o objeto como um dificultador e sim um facilitador.. porem o problema esta nessa função que gero a lista de objetos,  pois pelos meus testes o problema não está na classe, e sim nesta função `guarda_word` que eu acho que deve ter algum referencia errada. por exemplo... instancia essa classe e adiciona itens nela e depois imprime `objeto.imprime_indices()`  vc vai notar que esta contabilizando corretamente

Comment: @RuyNeto descobri o problema! o erro esta no `def __init__(self,palavra):`  vou atualizar td pra vcs verem

Comment: Bom dia. A saída do programa aqui https://repl.it/MQXR/2 não é nada parecido com a puseste na pergunta.

Comment: @Miguel é porque como mencionei nos comentarios acima.. eu consegui resolver o problema e atualizei o codigo na pergunta para o que está funcionando

Comment: @WilliamHenrique ok, percebi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa complexidade toda não é necessária quando você está programando em `Python`!

Esse simples programa é capaz de retornar o que você deseja:

```
from collections import Counter

arquivos = [ 'texto1.txt', 'texto2.txt', 'texto3.txt' ]

def obter_palavras( arqs ):
    ap = []

    for a in arqs:
        with open( a,'r' ) as f:
            ap += [ (a,p) for p in f.read().split() ]

    cnt = Counter(ap).items()
    dic = { p:[] for a, p in ap }

    for p in dic.keys():
        for a in arqs:
            for k, n in cnt:
                if k == (a,p):
                    dic[p].append((a,n))

    return dic


print obter_palavras( arquivos )
```

**texto1.txt**

```
alpha beta gamma delta
zero um dois tres
kilo mega giga tera
terra agua ar fogo
```

**texto2.txt**

```
zero um dois tres
zero um dois tres
kilo mega giga tera
```

**texto3.txt**

```
alpha beta gamma delta
alpha beta gamma delta
kilo mega giga tera
```

Saída:

```
{
    'mega': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 1)],
    'kilo': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 1)],
    'dois': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 2)],
    'zero': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 2)],
    'tera': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 1)],
    'terra': [('texto1.txt', 1)],
    'um': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 2)],
    'beta': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 2)],
    'ar': [('texto1.txt', 1)],
    'agua': [('texto1.txt', 1)],
    'delta': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 2)],
    'alpha': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 2)],
    'tres': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 2)],
    'fogo': [('texto1.txt', 1)],
    'giga': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto2.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 1)],
    'gamma': [('texto1.txt', 1), ('texto3.txt', 2)]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Também acho que está complicando o problema.
Acho que usar um dict seria bem mais simples. Procure no Google a classe Counter do Python.

Sobre seu código, você está contando na variavel aux, mas retornando counter. A variável counter conta as palavras da lista e aux as ocorrencias da palavra nessa lista. Então para obter a saída que deseja o certo seria retornar aux, não?

Comment: descobri o problema! o erro esta no def __init__(self,palavra):

Comment: agora o código esta correto.. arrumei.. ele... ta funcionando corretamente